# Why is there usually a reference to Java when when people talk about C#?

Tags: java, c#

I don't know much about C# but I've been programming in Java for a few months now. I had always heard what C and C++ were, but was a little curious about where C# came from. I'm a little confused about the C# language since even though it's one of the 'C' languages (C, C++, C#), on the other hand all of my professors seem to line it up against Java, and not the others.

If anyone can clarify that would be great :)

Comment: By any chance, have you looked at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language) ?

Comment: Just to quote a friend of mine, which is C# dev and teacher when asking him about C# : « you know java ? Then just change the compiler and it should work just fine ». He was obviously ironic, but wanted to emphasis how similar the 2 plateforms are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because Java and C# are extremely similar: They are both class-based OOP languages with single inheritance and interfaces, strong static typing, garbage collection built into the language, copy semantics that bind to types (value types vs. reference types), generics, namespace hierarchies, reflection, and they both run on a virtualized environment (JRE / .NET runtime). They also share a large part of their syntax.

The other languages from the "C-like" family are different from both Java and C# in many regards: C doesn't have classes, it is weakly-typed, it does not have garbage collection, copy semantics are explicit on use, it compiles directly to machine code, and it lacks generics (offering C Preprocessor macros and implicit casts instead). C++ does have classes, but uses multiple inheritance instead of interfaces; it also offers templates, which are superficially similar to generics but work differently under the hood; it is similar to C in most other regards. Javascript, also very similar to C in its syntax, shares garbage collection and a virtualized environment with Java and C#, but it uses dynamic typing, prototype-based OOP, and it does not use the half-way compilation approach of Java and C#.

Comment: I'm not sure you can compare java primitives to C# value-types..

Comment: @MattDavey: They behave pretty much the same, except that C# lets you define your own value types, beyond the built-in primitives, whereas in Java, all user-defined classes are automatically reference types. Other than that, the mechanisms are the same.

Comment: sounds like you have a broader range of experience across the languages so I will defer to your expertise :)

Answer (score 13):

C# is a managed code (compiled to bytecode and run on a virtual machine) language developed by Microsoft to serve as one of the core languages of the .NET framework. It features garbage collection and easy integration with other languages.

It gets lined up with Java because has most of the same features, a C like syntax, managed code execution model, and an automatic garbage collector. It's also an "easy" Object Oriented Language.

It resulted from an effort by Microsoft to develop a VM for Java until Sun sued them over it. Thus that project was shelved and the .NET project took over as Microsoft's effort to do a managed code environment mainly aimed at desktop applications.

You can write a lot of things in C# and run them in a fair number of places now with the Mono framework but it still lacks the shear power of C or C++ as well as being substantially harder to massacre your ambiguously owned cloned feet.

Anything that uses the XNA framework was likely written at least in part in C#.

Comment: @WorldEngineer Can you provide some references for *It resulted from an effort by Microsoft to develop a VM for Java until Sun sued them over it.*? I think you are confusing [VisualJ++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B#Sun.27s_litigation_against_Microsoft) with C#.

Comment: What does it means `as well as being substantially harder to massacre your ambiguously owned cloned feet`? Is this against C++ or against C#?

Comment: @YannisRizos C# was what Microsoft did when they weren't allowed to embrace and extend Java.

Comment: @xanatos C++ - it's an old joke about multiple inheritance and so forth. The original goes along the lines of C: Shoot yourself in the foot. C++: Make 10 copies of the foot, shoot all of them at random. Got to a hospital where they can't figure out which feet to treat as some are alias for others.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen C# born Jan 1999, J++ died Jan 2004... C# was already 5 years old when Microsoft *weren't allowed to embrace and extend Java.*. And J++ was developed under licence from Sun, so they were indeed allowed and seemed at first to want to embrace Java (why bother licencing at all), they just never actually bothered to do a good enough job with it i.e. making it compatible with Sun's implementation. C# may started out as an effort to emulate Java's platform and ecosystem, but it definately wasn't an effort to develop an MS JVM as WorldEngineer claims.

Comment: Also, when did Sun sue MS over C# or dotnet?

Comment: Microsoft did have their own JVM and did get sued by Sun. It's a bit hazy, but I think it was around 1997ish? The .NET platform was supposed to be the next version of COM, it was called something like COMX. I seem to remember there being details about it in : CLR via C# 3rd Edition by Jeffrey Richter in the first chapter or two.

Comment: @YannisRizos - you confuse the life of J++ with the life of the Microsoft JVM.  Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Java_Virtual_Machine

Comment: Cool. Since Sun did sue as early as 1997, it stands to logic that a major factor towards C# development was to replace MS JVM and J++ with a homegrown platform and language(s). Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Yes. And C# started out very similar to Java. I even remember reading one of the first books on C# in which the author explained that, er, well, C# is very similar to Java but, er, good ideas should be adopted and developed further... Stuff like that.

Comment: @Giorgio: Unfortunately many ideas which may have been okay in the absence of value types (e.g. the merging of `.` and `->`, or use of `==` for both value and reference comparisons) were brought in from Java without regard for whether they would play nicely with value types.